# How do you build a conditional form?

Tags: 8, forms

How do I build a form with :

- optgroup select for subject
- conditional display of informations depending on the selected subject
- conditional display of a part of the form if a checkbox is ticked

Example :

**[ Subject** select optgroup **⌄ ]**

*Conditional display : The content below varies depending on what is selected from the drop-down menu.*

If you are looking for informations about [replace with selected subject] please have a look a this page before : [link to the page]

**[ Checkbox ]** I can't find what I am looking for on this page.

*Conditional display : The form below is displayed only if the checkbox is ticked.*

- Name : **[text box]**
- Email : **[email box]**
- Message : **[text area]**

**[Submit button]**

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) We don't provide tutorials on how to implement that. But we can help you fix it when you update your question and provide the steps we need to know to reproduce a narrowly scoped and detailed problem. Thank you for your understanding

Comment: I think this can be easily achieved through the conditional fields module. Another way would be to learn form API and do it programmatically.
Other modules that might help you are: webforms, multistep forms, rules and business rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement all of this conditional logic using the Webform contrib module:

http://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Once you install the module, it provides its own documentation within your Drupal site, and even has links to excellent tutorial videos by module maintainer Jacob Rockowitz.

You could also Google "Drupal Webform conditional" and find tutorials like this one:

https://youtu.be/ic4wu-iZd4Y

That should be enough to get you started.

In the rare event that the Webform module doesn't implement all your form logic, you can export your Webform to YAML and it's a trivial exercise to translate that to Drupal Form API module code (with conditional `#states`) as PHP in a custom module, so it's always good to get as far as you can using just Webform.